# How to access data retrieved into an anonymous inner class (a listener) from the enclosing class?

Tags: java, arraylist, anonymous-class

I have retrieved a List of strings from Firestore.  I want to populate a spinner with this data.  I know that an inner class can only access a variable from the enclosing class if that variable is declared final.  But for some reason, the IDE is telling me that it cannot be a List, but must be an *array of a single element*!?

Because what I am trying to do must be so very commonplace, I suspect I am being dumber than usual and missing the obvious...but I just can't see it.

I have read what Oracle's Java documentation has to say about nested & inner & anonymous classes, to no avail.

```
private void setUpSpinners(DocumentReference DBStructureDocRef){

    List<String> allUnitTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    DBStructureDocRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                        allUnitTypes = (List<String>) documentSnapshot.get(KEY_ALL_UNIT_TYPES);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Document does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    // then go on to do something with the data retrieved in allUnitTypes
```

When allUnitTypes is not declared as final I get the message:  Variable 'allUnitTypes' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.

When I declare allUnitTypes final, I get the message:  Cannot assign a value to final variable 'allUnitTypes'

Comment: Well, are you calling this method from another class? (If yes, make the method not private)

Comment: make the variable final - then populate the list instead of reassign it: `allUnitTypes.addAll(...)`. It would probably make sense to use an Adapter and link it to your Spinner instead of using the list.

Comment: I am calling the OnSuccessListener from within a private method setUpSpinners.

Comment: The recommendation to "populate the list instead of reassign it" works like a charm.  Thank you.  (So I was not being "dumber than usual" but unfortunately still highly ignorant.

Comment: And yes, the spinner will have an adapter to set the contents:  final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allUnitTypes) {